# Python 3: Theoretical question about the use of variables in functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, theory

I have a theoretical question about Python 3.0 based on the example below:

```
def bookstore(book,price):
    return ("book Type: "+ book.capitalize() + " costs $" + price)

book_entry=input('Enter book type: ')
price_entry=input('Enter book type price: ')

print (bookstore(book_entry,price_entry))
```

By accident I got this script working, but I don't fully understand WHY it need to be done this way.
It is about the following part:

```
def bookstore(book,price):       AND       print (bookstore(book_entry,price_entry))
```

1. Why should the variables [*book_entry & price_entry*] be entered in the print-funtion instead of in the definition-function [*book,price*]?
2. How is communication possible between the variables? The def function is the only connection, but the variable name are different, how can the code accept this difference without giving an error?

Comment: Variable names don't matter. Only the number and position of arguments is important for unnamed arguments. Python also has other types of arguments that don't need to be positionally-fixed (keyword arguments)

Comment: Function calls and parameter passing are fundamental concepts in computer programming. This question is too general for SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to give a complete answer as to why and what is happening here, first we need to talk about the concept of "scope".
Each function (and for loop, while loop etc) "lives in its own world" in terms of memory. What does that mean? Assume I have a function named "foo1" and another function named "foo2". Within foo1, I have a variable named x. From within foo2 - I cannot access that variable (x), since it "lives" in the scope ("world") of foo1.
In python, you have one global scope (the.py file itself) and a scope for each function. A variable created in a scope that is not the global scope is called a "local" variable. 
This brings us to function arguments - in your case, the variables named "book" and "price" in the "bookstore" function. Note - these are local variables in the scope of the function "bookstore". How do they get their values? From the function call!
In you case, within the "print" function you called "bookstore" with 2 arguments - "book_entry" and "price_entry". When you did this, you copied the content of those variables to the scope of the function and gave them a new name - "book" and "price", according to the order you sent them to the function "bookstore". 
Then, from the function you return a string. 
So, what happens is the computer first executes the call to "bookstore" and then executes "print" with what "bookstore" returned.

Answer (score 0):

Parameters to functions are references to objects, which are passed by value. When you pass a variable to a function, python passes the reference to the object to which the variable refers (the value). Not the variable itself.

If the value passed in a function is immutable, the function does not modify the caller’s variable. If the value is mutable, the function may modify the caller’s variable in-place: